# What;s a correct way to use APOC.when in that query?

Tags: graph, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I need to select different nodes in dependence of `rel_type` var. So it'll be ideal for me if returning a node from `APOC.when` is possible. As alternative way it's ok for returning an ID of matched node. How can I solve that task by one of these ways?

`Legal_Entity` and `Natural_Person` is a classes of nodes interested us;

`hid_party` - a parameter that each nodes has. Used as unique ID;

`rel_type` may be 'LEGAL' or 'PHYSICAL'. Depending on this parameter, different nodes should be selected.

Example:

```py
match (legal:Legal_Entity {hid_party : '157456674'})
with legal,
     '422741957' as second_hid,
     'LEGAL' as rel_type

     CALL apoc.when(
        'LEGAL' = 'LEGAL',
        'match (second:Legal_Entity {hid_party : second_hid}) return second as second_node',
        'match (second:Natural_Person {hid_party : second_hid}) return second as second_node',
        {second_hid:second_hid}
        ) YIELD value

return value.second_node
```

Comment: What's the issue with the current query? `apoc.when()` can return nodes

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen IDK why but it didn't return matched nodes when I tried to use it. Can you make a simple example?

Comment: I gave an example as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should work, but maybe we're missing how you pass the rel type as parameter.

Simple example :

Stub graph

```
CREATE (:LegalEntity {id: 123})
CREATE (:NaturalPerson {id: 456})
```

Then set a dummy parameter in the browser

```
:param relType => 'LEGAL'
```

Verify the list of parameters available for a query

```
:params

// result
{
  "relType": "LEGAL"
}
```

Then example of using `apoc.when` depending on the parameter

```
CALL apoc.when($relType = 'LEGAL', 
'MATCH (n:LegalEntity) RETURN n',
'MATCH (n:NaturalPerson) RETURN n',
{}
)
YIELD value
RETURN value.n AS n
```

Returns the expected `LegalEntity` node

```
╒══════════╕
│"n"       │
╞══════════╡
│{"id":123}│
└──────────┘
```

Change the parameter to something else

```
:param relType => 'OtherValue'
```

Run the same query, result is different

```
╒══════════╕
│"n"       │
╞══════════╡
│{"id":456}│
└──────────┘
```